# How can I rename Excel worksheets using NetOffice?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am trying to use NetOffice to create excel workbooks in my c# application and have caught a snag trying to rename worksheets and using sorts on ranges of cells.  The following lines of code are not recognized by NetOffice and I am struggling to find a way to rename worksheets and sort ranges of cells using NetOffice.

```
workbook.Worksheets[sheetCountPlusONe].name = "Event " + sheetCountPlusONe.ToString() + " Results";
```

And this also doesn't work.  This is where I am declaring and sorting a range of cells:

```
Excel.Range valueRange;
Excel.Range placeRange;
placeRange = worksheet.get_Range("A14", "A" + (14 + (registrationForm.numberofCompetitors - 1)).ToString());
valueRange = worksheet.get_Range("A14", "K"+(14+(registrationForm.numberofCompetitors-1)).ToString());
valueRange.Sort(valueRange.Columns[3, Type.Missing], Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlGuess, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns, Excel.XlSortMethod.xlPinYin, Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal, Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal, Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal);
placeRange.Sort(placeRange.Columns[1, Type.Missing], Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlGuess, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns, Excel.XlSortMethod.xlPinYin, Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal, Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal, Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal);
```

Comment: Did you try .Name? [This reference (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.name.aspx#Y0) shows it as a capitalized property.

Comment: Yes I did and it worked sort of.  I wish there was more documentation on how to use NetOffice online.  The website is only so helpful.  I'm having trouble implementing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am wondering about your question. The following code works fine:

```
Excel.Application excelApplication = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workBook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Add();
Excel.Worksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheets[1] as Excel.Worksheet;
workSheet.Name = "AnyNameYouWant";
```

Answer (score 0):

Is "sheetCountPlusOne" an integer one greater than the size of your collection?  You have to add a sheet before you can rename it.

For sorting, I would recommend using .NET 4's named parameters if at all possible, and avoid the headache of a list of Type.Missing.